# jBPM KIE WORKBENCH hangs on "loading" when I click "Administration" and fully don't work in Firefox

Tags: jbpm

I installed and start.demo jBPM on win7 x64.

1. After I tried to use it through firefox 30 it hangs at localhost:8080/jbpm-console/ . Why?
   [image]
2. After I tried to use it in Chrome it works. However after hour of playing with jBPM it hangs at "Administration". It wasn't first time when I click at Administration, before it works. After this every time when I am opening "Administration" it hangs with
   [image]

stop.demo and start again, cleaning cookies, private browser mode haven't helped. How to fix this?

Comment: In my case it only work with IE

Comment: Thanks, I already have decided to use Activity BPM